# Algorithm not found

Tags: pyqgis

I'm trying to combine shapefiles in a folder of mine, but everytime i run it or run a variation of this it gives me the same error, "Error: Algorithm not found"

this is my code:

```
import os
import glob
import urllib
import sys
import zipfile


import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing

Processing.initialize()
Processing.updateAlgsList()

processing.alglist("merge")
processing.alghelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")

pth = "C:/Users/Light/Desktop/qgis_data/tiled_footprints/"

files = glob.glob(pth + "*.shp")

out = pth + "merged.shp"

processing.runandload("saga:mergeshapeslayers", files.pop(0), ";".join(files), out)
```

I followed the advice of this thread here: [Error: Algorithm not found (QGIS)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152762/error-algorithm-not-found-qgis)

and I created the path, PYTHON_PATH in the system environment variables but still nothing.

Comment: Is SAGA installed properly? Can you see SAGA algorithms in the processing panel?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be calling the correct algorithm.

first you are looking at the qgis merge

```
processing.alghelp("qgis:mergevectorlayers")
```

later on you're calling a non-existing saga algorithm

```
processing.runandload("saga:mergeshapeslayers", files.pop(0), ";".join(files), out)
```

the saga merge algorithm is called `"saga:mergelayers"`

[image]